# misaligned openSSL in OSX?

Tags: high-sierra, openssl

Errors are being generated on OSX 10.13.6 when using curl with protocol https, but not with browsers.

```
curl https://letsencrypt.org/
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

Thus the browsers seem to have their own TLS libraries with a different result from the system.

When querying:

```
> openssl version
LibreSSL 2.2.7
```

Yet there is a directory  `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/`

I believe these errors would be removed if the system were relying on openSSL 1.1.
How can that be set?

Comment: Where openssl executable is does not tell you where the library that curl uses. Where is the curl that you use

Comment: `which curl` returns  `/usr/bin/curl`.  I see that `curl-config` has an entry `   --configure)
        echo --enable-hidden-symbols --enable-threaded-resolver --with-gssapi --with-ssl=/usr/local/libressl`

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: question amended.